Using both C99 and C++11 in Code::Blocks 16.01
I recently realized that Code::Blocks (I use 16.01) was not configured to use C++11 (nullptr), but that I also need at least C99 to be present instead of ANSI C. For some reason the Have gcc follow the 1999 ISO C language standard [-std=c99] and any of the g++ options can't both be selected at the same time. Also, the ANSI option is separate unlike the C99 one. Is this specific to this (Code::Blocks) version? I checked and this doesn't have the specific solution like others. I understand that I'm setting the std option, but these are two separate binaries and it doesn't seem justified.
Thanks for reaching out.

What are you really doing? Do you have a mixed-language project? Or are you trying to mix C and C++ in the same source files? What are the problems, errors, messages, etc. that you get, by the IDE or by the compilers?

C++ isn't C and the ANSI C++ standards are not synchronized with ANSI C standards. Mixing C++ and C was already a bad idea in 1992 when "Effective C++" was published, warning against that kind of code.

There may be mixed languages in some cases of writing custom containers or similar, but I am actually having source code compiled without a holding project. The question is about setting gcc and g++ to use c99 and c++11. There aren't mixed languages except in edgecases.

Just ignore the CB's checkboxes, and manually type in the flags. There's an "other flags" textbox somewhere in project settings.

Quite the opposite, it's two different languages with conflicting concepts and standards. On top of that, there's a 12 year difference between the two (already incompatible) standards. You can't tell the compiler to act like two different standards at the same time. If you have a C and a C++ project, compile them using the appropriate settings in each case

When compiling C code use gcc with the appropriate flags for C. When compiling C++ code use g++ with the appropriate flags for C++.

@HolyBlackCat, I'm not certain how to do that for gcc and g++ separately

If your compiler suite does not support at least C99 and C++11 by default, perhaps consider upgrading it.

@n.m.couldbeanAI, it does support it, I was in a way hoping not to change compiler flags when switching from C to the other one. It seems they're all combined besides "C mode", so I'll just switch them when using C I guess.
